# Settings for display brightness not saved in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: brightness

I have bought HP ENVY 15t laptop and installed Ubuntu 13.10 on it. The first annoying thing I faced with was restoring brightness settings to 100% after reboot. So I had to adjust it every time I reboot. I googled and found variety of workarounds of this issue. Recently I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and the issue is still here. I really don't understand is it so difficult to save brightness settings and restore them after reboot. As a user I don't want to look for workarounds and edit configuring files or install additional utils for settings already implemented in System Settings every time I install Ubuntu. Also checkbox "Dim screen to save power" has no effect.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! To me it is not exactly clear; is this post a statement or a request for help?